# Use the following business rules to create a Crow’s Foot ERD

Tags: database-design, erd, entity-framework

[image]

[image]

Is there any mistake in the ERD???? it looks weird.

Comment: Please explain why it looks weird to you--this will help someone explain it so that you can understand whatever problems may exist.

Comment: should i add the relationship between Manager and Soccer Club??

Comment: I don't know if i understand the business rules

Comment: The manager relates to the club.  A member probably shouldn't relate to a manager as it isn't necessary--you can join members to soccerclub and manager to find a member's manager.  You probably need to review database normalization--once you understand normalization, things will be clear.